# Wavy arrows in xy-pic

Tags: xy-pic, graphs

What method should I use, to draw beautiful wavy arrows.

So far I tried the following.
I use `xy-pic` package, there I use `@{~>}` definition for the arrow.

The code I've composed is like this:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\mbox{
\xygraph{
!{<0cm,0cm>;<1cm,0cm>:<0cm,1cm>::}
!{(0,0) }*+{\bullet_{x}}="x"
!{(2,0) }*+{\bullet_{v''}}="v"
!{(4,0) }*+{\bullet_{y}}="y"
!{(2,1) }*+{\bullet_{u}}="u"
!{(2,-2) }*+{\bullet_{z}}="z"
"x":@{~>}"v"
"v":@{~>}"y"
"y":@/_/@{~>}"u"
"u":"v"
"v":@{~>}"z"
}}
\end{figure}
```

And the result is like this:

[image: A graph with wavy arrows]

The problems that I see in this drawing are:

- In the arrows from x to v'' and from v'' to y the composition of last "~" and the ending ">" is not good.
- The arrow from v'' to z is cutted after each "~"
- The arrow from y to u looks awful.

I search for a tip how to improve the quality of the figure. Thanks.

Comment: I can not answer your question, but I believe that the best would be not to use `xy-pic` - use `TikZ` instead.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen I had a feeling that I have to switch to `TikZ`. I haven't used it before, so I wanted to stay with `xy-pic`. Thanks for advise.

Comment: And may be investigate `tike-cd` for this kind of graphs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default arrow styles in the [`xypic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xypic) are rather bad,arrow heads/tips styles can be changed with font family and it's size as mentioned in [Ref­er­ence man­ual:Section 10 More Tips extension: Page 27](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/doc/xyrefer.pdf) with

```
\SelectTips{<family>}{<size>}
```

Those broken arrows and inferior typesetting quality can be improved by loading
[xypdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/doc/xypdf.pdf)  package with `pdf` as an option like this `\usepackage[pdf]{xypic}`

Finally the improved version of your MWE with above tweaks and output is as follows, although you might consider `tikz-cd` for this job.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,pdf]{xy}
\begin{document}
\SelectTips{cm}{11}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\mbox{
\xygraph{
!{<0cm,0cm>;<1cm,0cm>:<0cm,1cm>::}
!{(0,0) }*+{\bullet_{x}}="x"
!{(2,0) }*+{\bullet_{v''}}="v"
!{(4,0) }*+{\bullet_{y}}="y"
!{(2,1) }*+{\bullet_{u}}="u"
!{(2,-2) }*+{\bullet_{z}}="z"
"x":@{~>}"v"
"v":@{~>}"y"
"y":@/_/@{~>}"u"
"u":"v"
"v":@{~>}"z"
}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the end I used tikz to reach the goal. But according to the question, your answer solves it in the required way. Therefore, I accept it.

Answer (score 7):

I realize the OP wanted a solution with `xy-pic`, but since there was such low activity and others may find them useful, here are some possible solutions using `tikz-cd` and plain `tikz`:

**Option 1: `tikz-cd`**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[%
  arrows={decorate, decoration={snake,segment length=1.64mm,amplitude=0.2mm}}
]
~            & & u \arrow[decorate=false]{d} & &                           \\
x \arrow{rr} & & v'' \arrow{rr} \arrow{dd}   & & y \arrow[bend right]{llu} \\
             & &                             & &                           \\
             & & z                           & &
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Option 2: `tikz`**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  foo/.style={%
    ->,
    shorten >=4pt,
    shorten <=4pt,
    decorate,
    decoration={%
      snake,
      segment length=1.64mm,
      amplitude=0.2mm,
      pre length=4pt,
      post length=4pt,
    }
  }
]
  \coordinate (v'') at ( 0, 0);
  \coordinate (u)   at ( 0, 1);
  \coordinate (x)   at (-2, 0);
  \coordinate (y)   at ( 2, 0);
  \coordinate (z)   at ( 0,-2);
  \foreach \pt in {u,v'',x,y,z} {
    \fill (\pt) circle (2pt) node[below right] {$\pt$};
  }
  \draw[foo] (x) -- (v'');
  \draw[foo] (v'') -- (y);
  \draw[foo] (v'') -- (z);
  \draw[foo] (y) to[in=-5,out=120] (u);
  \draw[foo,decorate=false] (u) -- (v'');
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm wondering if it's possible to create sharper wavy arrows, like the wave of the symbol \leadsto. If so, do you mind adding an explanation in your answer? Also, if you could explain how to make it so that the default arrow is "standard", but could toggle [decorations=true] or something to make it wavy, that would also be very nice.